# Outlook doesn't show date on the preview when eml is converted to msg using msgkit

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, msgkit

i tried converting the .eml to .msg in c# using [msgkit](https://github.com/Sicos1977/MsgKit) so my `.eml` file looks like this

```
Date: Thu, 30 Jan 2020 12:09:26 +0530
```

its a simple .eml file i tried converting the .eml to .msg using online converter as well when viewed from ole compound viewer the files look almost the same but the msgkit converted one doesn't show recieved date in the preview when opened with outlook. online converted shows received date correctly but the one converted using msgkit says `None` .I want to know what parameter does outlook look for when picking up the recieved date on preview. i tried giving different properties as well from https://github.com/vikramarsid/msg_parser/blob/master/msg_parser/properties/ms_props_id_map.py

[image: outlook preview]

Comment: msgkit comes with full source code, why not step through it and see what it does?

Comment: @Dmitry i did step in and saw what it does i did resolve some of the problems but couldn't figure out what field is outlook looking for picking the date in the preview since all the substring fields in the compound files of both online converted one and msg kit converted looks the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `PR_CLIENT_SUBMIT_TIME` (`0x00390040`) and `PR_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_TIME` (`0x0E060040`) MAPI properties are set.

You can take a look at the resulting MSG file and its properties in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) - click OpenIMsgOnIStg button.

Also, if using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am also its author) is an option, converting EML to MSG is as simple as

```
RDOSession session = new RDOSession();
RDOMail msg = session.CreateMessageFromMsgFile(@"c:\temp\test.msg");
msg.Import(@"c:\temp\test.eml", rdoSaveAsType.olRFC822);
msg.Save();
```